# Page break after a certain condition in ssrs

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to Reports in SSRS. I am facing problem in page break in ssrs. The problem is that I want to break the page whenever the sum of amount field in my table is greater than or equal to 20000.
I want an output like this:

Page1
A       2000
B       6000
C       4000
D       5000
total  17000

Page 2
E       5000
F       5000
G       5000
H       5000
total  20000

and so on...

Can anybody help me get out the solution please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you didn't include E on page 1 because you didn't want the total to exceed 20000. So you want to break *before* it exceeds rather than *after* it exceeds.

Comment: Yes I want the total to be lesser than 20000 or equal to 20000

Comment: I think you'll have to use Visual Basic to keep track of the running total and then reset after a page break. I poked around on Google for a solution. Unfortunately I don't have SSRS and can't offer much more help.

Comment: Even I have tried a lot and searched all over in google.

Comment: Its okay...Thanks for ur solution I ll try it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make changes in my dataset to get the running total of the column
and then I gave the page break condition on the details group and now I can see that the page is getting broken when the sum is exceeding 20000.

I couldn't have got the idea to change the dataset query without your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

A way to achieve this wanted result would be to group the data correctly before you send the DataSource to the reporter.
So you'll have to create a custom DataTable and DataSet where you for example add a new column containing a key that represents the data that should be grouped.
Next you can place everything in the List element and group on that key. Inside the rectangle you can place the Tablix to achieve the wanted result.

To get the pages to break correctly you should edit the rectangle size to fit the body of the page perfectly. And make sure that both properties `Add a page break after` and `Keep contents together on a single page, if possible` are checked.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you are trying to say...it would be better if you can give an example for this solution.

Comment: What part don't you understand? Perhaps, if you add the DataTable you are using now to your question I'll update my answer to fit your example exactly. You also didn't mention what programming language you're using, c# or vb?

Comment: Why be so obscure? You basically are asking the OP to create a calculated column in the dataset and use it to group in SSRS. Clearly OP doesn't want to do that. The programming language is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: Writing an expression that does the kind of grouping he's requesting is extremely troublesome. I'm just offering a simple solution to the problem. The OP simply responded that he doesn't understand it but seems interested. Therefore I'm willing to apply it to his example but I need to know in what environment he's working. Your comment is however completely obsolete and not constructive in any way. If you have a better answer to his problem, please feel free to do a suggestion.

Comment: the programming language i am using is vb

Comment: My intent was to just point that OP wants to handle the "grouping" in SSRS and not in the dataset(which not always is a viable option). I came across this question and found it be quite interesting. And so I find it mind numbing when the original context is being questioned when it is crystal clear.

Comment: @PoojaPandey you really need to learn how to ask questions on this site. You have tagged this question under "sql-server-2008" and NOW telling that the programming language is VB. Sending all sorts of confusing signals.

Comment: Anyway, I do agree that it is a lot easier to handle this in dataset by creating a *running totals* field.

Comment: Actually m new to this site and m learning all the things and yes i realised that i have to keep track of running totals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Don't forget to flag this question as answered if you did. If you used a different approach post your solution so others can learn from it.